# How to use pagination?

Tags: templates, pagination

I don't know how to get pagination to work, seems like it should be simple but I just don't know. I am new to this particular aspect of expression engine. Can anyone help.

Here was what I did put in but for the pagination it just renders the curly brace pagination code and the rest of the channel entry code renders correctly. 
Thanks

```
{exp:channel:entries 
   channel="publications" 
   orderby="title"
   sort="asc"
   paginate="both"
   Limit="15" 
   }
          <h3>{pub_year}</h3>
          <h5> {title}</h5> 
       {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
        {/paginate}             
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: What version of EE are you running? Your code is correct (except for your capitalized `Limit`) - though older versions required you add `{if paginate} ... {/if}` so that the tags would get stripped if there was no pagination to render.

Comment: I am on EE v2.9.2